# LinkageError on WebSphere 9 for javax.transaction.* classes

Tags: websphere, linkageerror

I have a web application that used to run fine on many web servers (tomcat, jboss, weblogic and websphere). Now, however, it has an error when deploying on WebSphere 9.

The app contains the jar javax.transaction-api-1.2. Some of its classes, e.g., `javax.transaction.xa.XAResource`, are also included in Java SE, but not all of them. Some are specific to Java EE and are required by some 3rd-party libraries in my app. The app is always deploying with child-first (parent-last) classloader.
WebSphere 9 throws this error during startup when the app tries to load the Oracle JDBC driver:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation: loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@7157be44" previously initiated loading for a different type with name 
"javax/transaction/xa/XAResource" defined by loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@422c7b1b"
```

Note that we aren't actually using XA transactions in the app, we are using regular transactions.

On other servers, and previous versions of WebSphere, it was never a problem. The server didn't care that we load `XAResource` from inside the war, even if it was previously loaded somewhere in the server. Now WebSphere 9 is different, it says that the app classloader already loaded this class from the server, but I don't know why or when did this happen.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end we did two things to solve this problem.

1) We upgraded the jta jar to version 1.3 (link [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.3)). This jar solves the problem by avoiding duplicate classes - it contains only J2EE classes and omits the J2SE classes that are already included in the JVM.
2) We upgraded WebSphere server from 9.0.0.7 to 9.0.0.11.

At the time, I suspected just upgrading the jar should suffice, but our QA had some issues with it and they also upgraded the server. Due to lack of time, we didn't investigate it further and just decided to do both.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the transaction API from your application. JTA 1.2 is already included in the server and provides no value in your applications. It's always risky to bring Java EE/SE APIs in a parent-last class loader unless you are 100% certain that they are technically necessary, because they can lead to issues like this one.

I can't say how this worked in previous server versions (there have been some Java-level changes in enforcing linkage issues like this), but the solution is reasonably straightforward.

Comment: I need that jar for other servers, on which jta is not provided. I am trying to avoid having different war archives for different servers

Comment: Is there a technical reason that you're running with parent-last class loader policy? You only need that if you've got specific things in your app that you absolutely have to use your version in preference to the server's version. The risk of LinkageErrors is orders of magnitude higher with parent-last, because it makes it more likely that a class is defined by multiple class loaders.

Comment: of course there is a technical reason - parent-first class loader makes our application vulnerable to changes in the server environment and bugs in its libraries. We have been using parent-last for the last 15 years in this app, thoughout the evolution of j2ee and in many different servers. Using parent-last gives us isolation and stability, and until now it always worked. It works on jboss and weblogic as well, and on previous versions of websphere (and tomcat as well, which doesn't have jta)